# SQL transform table query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I got a problem transforming a table that looks like this

```
PropertyName | PropertyValue
---------------------------------
color    red
color    blue
size    big
size    small
```

into this:

```
Color  | Size
---------------------------------
red   big
red   small
blue   big
blue   small
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want every permutation of colours and sizes?

```
SELECT color, size FROM 
(
select distinct  PropertyValue AS color
from YourTable
where PropertyName = 'color'
) T1
CROSS JOIN 
(
select distinct  PropertyValue AS size
from YourTable
where PropertyName = 'size'
) T2
```

Comment: Okay, that`s a start. Thanks very much. But is there a way, to do it automatically for all PropertyNames and -Values? I mean without having to write a cross join for each propertyname?

Comment: Not in standard SQL. Can you tag your question with the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Then I guess I have to live with it. Thanks again.

Comment: @tombom - For SQL server you would need to use dynamic SQL to create a string similar to the above that you then execute.